# How to print the view of a Lightning Web Component, including colors?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to print the view of my LWC component in a way that would preserve the style of the component, especially the colors since the component uses a sort of color-coding system to display data. Having tried @media print specific styling, with and without the "!important" flag, as well as the html2canvas library, I am currently at my wit's end for nothing seems to be working. The former simply has no effect (I just get a black-and-white wireframe, as if the print-specific styling were not in place), and html2canvas gives me errors. Below is the method I'm trying to run:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => {
        let newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
});
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at eval (html2canvas.min.js:7)
at E (html2canvas.min.js:7)
at new I (html2canvas.min.js:7)
at n.exports (html2canvas.min.js:7)
at d (html2canvas.min.js:7)
at Proxy.o (html2canvas.min.js:7)
at Testlwc.displayPrinterFriendlyVersion (ls_emea_linechart.js:926)
at callHook (aura_proddebug.js:19578)
at aura_proddebug.js:6573
at runWithBoundaryProtection (aura_proddebug.js:8255)
```

Alternatively, when I try

```
html2canvas($('.html-canvas')).then(canvas => {...}
```

I get

```
[l.setAttribute is not a function]
```

My guess is that the doctoring the LWC framework does on the DOM elements strips them of some of the properties the library expects. And here's a simplified structure of what I'm trying to print:

```
<template>
<div>
    Irrelevant stuff here
</div>

<div class="html-canvas">
    <c-subcomponent>
    This component could be printed without the styles and still look OK
    </c-subcomponent>

    <lightning-card title="">
        Now this is what I want printed in color. There's a table here
        with divs styled using the 'background-color' and 'color' properties
        and I need that to show in print
    </lightning-card>
</div>
```

Worst of all is, even if html2canvas did process the DOM, it would probably still not solve the problem, as I distinctly recall reading in the LWC docs that styles don't get through when an element is appended using the appendChild() method.

Any ideas, anybody?

Comment: How are you trying to open your LWC? quick action or app?

Comment: Within Lightning, this is impossible. Between Locker Service and Web Component Shadow Roots, the DOM is inaccessible. Your best bet would be to attempt to load a @media print style dynamically with loadStyles, then try to print the current page. Even that would prove to be challenging to get just right.

Comment: @sfdcfox,
Your advice has worked like a charm - thank you so much! What I did was copy all the styling rules from both components' CSS files, surrounded them with the '@media print' directive and added the '!important' flag to every single one, then uploaded this collective stylesheet as a static resource and loaded it using loadStyles. After a little more tweaking, I got a printout that looks something like the on-screen view - not quite the same but that doesn't matter, as long as the crucial colors are in place (which they are). Many, many thanks once again!

Comment: @SebastianKamiński, i did same way what you did, but i am unable to get the color of selected radio group for print. can you add your solution as answer.

Comment: i added static resource with below css ` @media print{
 .slds-radio_button [type=radio]:checked+.slds-radio_faux,, 
.slds-radio_button [type=radio]:checked+.slds-radio_button__label, 
.slds-radio_button [type=radio]:checked+.slds-radio--button__label, 
.slds-radio--button [type=radio]:checked~.slds-radio--faux, 
.slds-radio--button [type=radio]:checked+.slds-radio_button__label, 
.slds-radio--button [type=radio]:checked+.slds-radio--button__label {
    color: var(--lwc-colorTextButtonBrand,#FFFFFF);
    background-color: red !important;
}
    
}